# How to configure the system in order to be able to hear the sound of the \a escape character?

Tags: command-line, audio, echo, escape-characters, bell

I read that if I execute:

```
echo -e "\a"
```

a sound emerges, but I executed this command several times and no sound happened.

Comment: In what terminal did you do this? Many systems are set up with a “visual bell” by default, which replaces the annoying sound by a less annoying visual effect.

Comment: I am using a transparent terminal on linux mint, it is a bash shell, when I execute echo -e "\a" nothing at all appears, no sound and no visual bell.

Comment: Which terminal emulator? Is it Gnome-terminal, Gnome Terminator, Konsole, …? You can see that by running `ps $PPID` in the shell, or by looking at the terminal emulator's title bar. And what's the output of `xset q |grep -i bell`?

Comment: bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100

Comment: And which terminal emulator?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without the information that Gilles has asked for, three times now.  The answer is _completely different_ for (say) fbterm, xfce4-terminal, and a kernel virtual terminal.  And even if you don't know the name of the emulator program, you can at least tell people what steps you take in order to access the terminal.  You're not even telling people whether it's an X program.  This information is right before you, but you're not supplying it and expecting people with no access to your computer to determine it clairvoyantly.

Comment: I can not deliver the information because I do not know how to obtain them, it surpasses my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

> First run `sudo modprobe pcspkr` and then beep should work.
>
> The reason this doesn't is because by default Ubuntu no longer loads
>   the hardware driver that produce beeps.

**EDIT** This should work on Mint as well, ignore my Ubuntu comment.  I am partial as that is what I have been on for so long

Some other items I have come across-

```
sudo xset b on
echo -e "\a"
```

Still no luck?

Why not just use the program `beep` ?

There is also [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/107618/362459)answer which seems to have helped some.

From what I have researched on the topic it seems that most people **HATE** the system beep and great efforts have been made from the kernal all the way up to window managers to prevent it from sounding.  For example `metacity` specifically captures this escape sequence to prevent this beep from sounding.  There are some workarounds but it seems like `beep` is a better alternative or just playing a sound in some other way.

Comment: i executed modprobe pcspkr as root, and the pcspkr LKM was indeed added as I checked by lsmod | grep pcspkr.  But when i executed echo -e "\a" again no sound appeared.

Comment: hmm well that was the first step at least, without that it 100% would not have worked.  Do you have speakers hooked up?  Do they work for other sounds?  Is there a specific setting in your terminal options to stop it?  I am not familiar with your terminal emulator sorry

Comment: Also issue `sudo xset b on` as well and try again

Comment: i am using a laptop, i guess it has build in pc-speakers, i do not know the name of my terminal, which terminal do you use ?

Comment: `gnome-terminal` is what is installed by default with ubuntu. However I am SSHed into all my boxes as they are headless servers so its a little different.  Most people HATE the system beep so there has been great effort to stop it from happening. Hence why you had to load the kernel module.

Comment: try this `sudo sh -c "echo -e '\a' > /dev/console"`

Comment: unfortunately sudo sh -c "echo -e '\a' > /dev/console" creates no sound, ... i executed echo $TERM   and the variable hold the value  xterm, i guess that is my terminal name.

Comment: Inside your terminal.  Edit-->Current Profile->General and check the Terminal Bell.  If that doesn't work, try just `beep`